# When type arguments are supplied for the constructor - then Diamond Operator cannot be used and Type Arguments must be supplied?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, jls, diamond-operator

Consider the following clause from the **JLS (§15.9)**

> It is a compile-time error if a class instance creation expression provides type
> arguments to a constructor but uses the diamond form for type arguments to the
> class.

The reason why this is not allowed is given as the following

> This rule is introduced because inference of a generic class's type arguments may influence
> the constraints on a generic constructor's type arguments.

Not very sure why this has been said so - consider the following typical usage of Type Parameters in the case of the generic class and the generic constructor:

```java
class Scratch<T,R> {
  public <K> Scratch(K k, T t, R r){
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scratch<Integer,Double> dd = new <String>Scratch<>("abdc",33,33.4); //compile error
  }
}
```

Here we have  the following:

- the Type parameter for the Constructor alone is K while for the class is {T,R}
- All these types are different from each other - and when the diamond operator is being used - the Class types cannot collide with the types being specified for the Constructor's type parameters.

**Then how is the above reason for "not allowing the diamond operator when Type arguments for the Constructor are being provided" valid?**. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In your case, yes, the type arguments don't "influence each other", but there are situations where they _do_ influence each other. It isn't unreasonable to decide to not implement a feature because this can happen in some (but not all) situations, is it?

Comment: Notice the word "may"  in the JLS quote. It doesn't say "always".

Comment: @Sweeper : Principle wise this is true - but is there any scenario currently where this is restriction of JLS is getting applicable?

Comment: Sure, just change `<K>` to `<K extends T>`. Now the constraints of `K` depends on what `T` has been inferred to.

Comment: @Sweeper : Excellent!!... this answers my question.

Comment: user16320675 - trying to preserve this question - as @Sweeper answered it accurately.